# Unable to upload anything to Wordpress site

Tags: uploads, permissions

I've had a Wordpress site working for (of course) years now, but suddenly it won't let me upload anything.

Attempting to add a new image gives me:

> **“filename.jpg” has failed to upload.**
>   Failed to write file to disk.

Attempting to update a plugin or theme gives me:

> An error occurred while updating [plugin or theme name]: **The package could not be installed. The package contains no files.**

I've checked permissions (I hadn't changed them), and folders are 755 and files are 644 (with the exception of wp-config.php which is 640). I tried chmod'ing wp-content to 775 but there was no difference.

Has anyone run into this before? Is there a log/some way of knowing what the actual problem is?

Comment: Sounds like your web host did something to you.  Any other symptoms with the site?

Comment: is there a space quota?

Comment: who is the folders owner? server or user?

Answer (score 0):

For me the system downloaded plugin versions to `/tmp/wpinstaller` where `/tmp` reached the max quota of 2 GiB over a couple of years. I deleted all files older than 30 days, and all (automatic) updates worked again. I guess I have to rinse and repeat in a couple of years.